# How to replace quotes in database

Tags: php, database

My problem is that when user enter any text which has "quotes" then it does not display data after the first `"`. So i used str_replace function like this

```
str_replace('"', "“", $courseName)
```

and in this i replaced that `"` with the `“` (MS-word quote) and this work correctly. Now the problem is that i have a large number of text fields and i have to apply this code on the all fields so either i have to done it manually or is there available any other solution.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Have you considered HTML escaping when outputting your database content?

Comment: Have a more robust approach to [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Quotes in the database shouldn't cause problems, unless you're not encoding it properly when displaying it. Show how you're storing the value and later retrieving and displaying it.

Comment: You can use REPLACE in SQL too: UPDATE table SET text=REPLACE(text,'"','“');

Comment: Can you show us code that saves your data?

Comment: $courseName = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlentities($row['Teach_RIMC_Course']));    This is the way in which i assigned a value to a variable.